# How to rename anonymous keys in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "chrysanthemum.jpg"
    1 => "http://site.loc/1"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "desert.jpg"
    1 => "http://site.loc/2"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "hydrangeas.jpg"
    1 => "http://site.loc/3"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "jellyfish.jpg"
    1 => "http://site.loc/4"
  ]
]
```

How to rename 0 to ['img'] and 1 to ['link'] in each array?

Trying this:

```
foreach($data as $array){
            $array['img']=$array[0];
            unset($array[0]);
            $array['link']=$array[1];
            unset($array[1]);
        }
```

but it doesn't work :c
Does php have a function for this task?

Comment: `$keys = ['img', 'link']; array_walk($myArray, function (&$value) { $value = array_combine($keys, $value); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways to do that.

The first, only put the `&` in the parameter:

```
foreach($data as &$array){
   $array['img']=$array[0];
   unset($array[0]);
   $array['link']=$array[1];
   unset($array[1]);
}
```

This will allow change the `$array`.

---

Another way is using the `array_map`:

```
$data = array_map(function($data) {
    return [
        'img' => $data['0'],
        'link' => $data['1']
    ];
}, $data);
```

---

*Response:*

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["img"]=>
    string(17) "chrysanthemum.jpg"
    ["link"]=>
    string(17) "http://site.loc/1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["img"]=>
    string(10) "desert.jpg"
    ["link"]=>
    string(17) "http://site.loc/2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["img"]=>
    string(14) "hydrangeas.jpg"
    ["link"]=>
    string(17) "http://site.loc/3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["img"]=>
    string(13) "jellyfish.jpg"
    ["link"]=>
    string(17) "http://site.loc/4"
  }
}
```

In both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access it via reference, right now you're just changing a copy of the data and not changing the data at all.

```
foreach($data as &$array){
    $array['img'] = $array[0];
    $array['link'] = $array[1];
    unset($array[0], $array[1]);
}
```